# Facing Problem in getting data from one page to another while login through Gmail in Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic.

1. I have made an Ionic Project name Login Through Gmail.
2. There is default page name Home & one generated page name PageOne.
3. **Here I have given a button on home.page.html, on clicking it a popup occurs "Choose an Account".**
4. When I'm clicking on individual account there, it display's name & email on the home.page.html**
5. **But, I want to display name & email on page-one.page.html .**
6. **So, want to know the things to do, to get name & email on page-one.page.html**

Here is the code

**home.page.html**

````
    <ion-toolbar color="warning">

      <ion-title>

        Social Login

      </ion-title>

    </ion-toolbar>

  </ion-header>

  <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  
  <div id="container">

    <strong>Ready to Social Login?</strong><br>

           <p>{{user | json}}</p>

    <ion-button color="success" (click)="gmailLogin()">Gmail Login</ion-button>

  </div>

   <p>User name: {{user.displayName}}</p><br>

   <p>E-mail ID: {{user.email}}</p>

  </ion-content>```


--------------------------------------------**home.page.ts**--------------------------------------------

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class HomePage {
  
  user:any = [];

  constructor(public googlePlus: GooglePlus, public store:Storage) {}

  gmailLogin(){

    this.googlePlus.login({})

  .then(result => this.user = result)

  .catch(err => this.user = `Error ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);

  }
  
  setTheValue(){

    this.store.set('name','user.displayName');

  }
  
  getTheValue(){

    this.store.get('name')

    .then((val)=>{console.log("UserName: "+val);

    });

  }
}

-------------------------------------**app.module.ts**------------------------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [AppComponent],
  
  entryComponents: [],
  
  imports: [
    
       BrowserModule, 
       
       IonicModule.forRoot(), 
     
       AppRoutingModule, 
    
       IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  
  providers: [
        GooglePlus,
       
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  })

export class AppModule {}
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/////// First Way ////////
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'one-page', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'one-page', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/one-page/one-page.module').then(m => m.OnePageModule) }, 
];
//////////

/////// Second Way ////////////
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/one-page/one-page.module').then(m => m.OnePageModule) }, 
];
//////////////////`enter code here`

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```